# Use Authentication function in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my controller like this

```
//Get the Helpers
var authHelper = require('authHelper');

//Route
router.get('/manager', authHelper.checkPerm(req, res, next), function(req, res) {

});
```

**my authHelper.js**

```
exports.checkPerm = function(req, res, next){
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/sign-in');
  }
}
```

This is the error i am getting

> router.get('/manager', authHelper.checkPerm(req, res, next),
>   function(req, res
>                                               ^ ReferenceError: req is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the method `checkPerm` when passing to the route parameter. Remove the parenthesis along with parameters `(req, res, next)`

Should be like this:

```
router.get('/manager', authHelper.checkPerm, function(req, res) ...
```